# How do I move an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS HDD from one computer to another?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Dell desktop to HP desktop.  Boot not recognized on HP; drive recognized when booted from USB

Comment: Are both UEFI or both BIOS? You may need to change UEFI/BIOS settings. And HP is not as friendly to boot other installs than "Windows Boot Manager". Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Do you physically want to move the HDD, or migrate the OS & data from it?

Comment: physically want to move the HDD. both BIOS